# Calling variable methods to handle ajax requests

Tags: php, object-oriented

I made a controller.php file to handle ajax requests, with $_POST parameters `action` and `module`

```
if (isset($_POST["action"])) {
    $action = strtolower($_POST["action"]);

    if ($action === "get_notification") {
        //  return session notification messages
       //...

    } elseif (isset($_POST["module"])) {
        require_once("libraries/class.module.php");
        $module = new Module;

        $moduleName = strtolower($_POST["module"]);

        //  check if module-name is valid
        if ($module->verify($moduleName)) {
            // load  $modulename class
            require_once("libraries/class.".$moduleName.".php");

            //  factory used to create instance of $moduleName
            require_once("libraries/class.factory.php");

            // note: moduleName class extends Module class
            $module = $Factory->create($moduleName);

            //  verify method of $moduleName verifies action/method parameter
            //  using method_exists and cross-checking against a permitted methods list

            if ($module->verify($action)) {
                $message = $module->$action();
                echo json_encode($message);

            } else {
                //  handle invalid requests
                echo json_encode(["0", "Invalid request received"]);
            }

        } else {
            //  handle invalid requests
            echo json_encode(["0", "Invalid request received"]);
        }

    } else {
        //  handle invalid requests
        echo json_encode(["0", "Invalid request received"]);
    }

} else {
    //  handle invalid requests
    echo json_encode(["0", "No request received"]);
}
```

But I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287789/check-if-class-has-method-in-php) post on Stack Overflow which advises against using variable methods. Should I replace mine with a switch case that checks each `$action` and calls corresponding method.

Comment: I certainly would. I always use an Action name that does not directly match what is really going to called/included. As an example:

`switch ($Action) {

 case 'doModify':
 case 'doAdd':

  require('AquaticWeeds_Common_Add-Mod.php');
  break;
`

Comment: @Dave So you are suggesting to go for switch _case instead of variable methods

Comment: Yes. As the post you referenced on SO pointed out, if you use a name directly from a posted variable you provide a way for someone to probe around looking for things that you may not want them to know about or see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, I would worry about getting rid of that awful code nesting you have. This nesting yields increased [cyclomatic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) which tends to lead to more buggy/fragile code and code that is harder to maintain.

So, at a minimum, think of re-writing your code like this:

```
if(empty($_POST['action'])) {
    echo json_encode(["0", "No request received"]);
    exit;
}

$action = strtolower($_POST['action']);
if($action === 'get_notification') {
    //  return session notification messages
    exit;
}

if(empty($_POST['module'])) {
    echo json_encode(["0", "No request received"]);
    exit;
}

require_once("libraries/class.module.php");
$module = new Module;
$moduleName = strtolower($_POST["module"]);

if(!$module->verify($moduleName)) {
    echo json_encode(["0", "No request received"]);
    exit;
}

// rest of code, now without nesting
```

---

Now, with that consideration out of the way.  Let's get to your main question. I am bothered by the fact that you call your script `controller.php` when what it is really doing is **routing**.  Your "modules" seem to really be your controllers and your "routing" is done in a very procedural fashion.

What you are really missing here is the concept of a router which can authoritatively map the request to a controller which can handle the request and to which request execution is then handed off. This is a concrete application of the [Inversion of Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) principle.  You are trying to keep control of request execution at the level of this script, which means you will have to continue to increase the complexity of this script as you add new use cases.

So to answer you question about using a switch. I would recommend that, rather than thinking about variable methods or switch as your alternatives, you think about proper routing and inversion of control as your alternative.

Envision a top level script here which looks like:

```
/**
 * An object that encapsulates the request data - URI, GET/POST data, etc.
 * that you can pass through your system
 */
$request = new Request();

/**
 * An object which can inspect the request and instantiate a controller to 
 * fulfill it. It then hands off script control to the controller.
 */
$router = new Router();
$controller = $router->getController($request);
$controller->execute();
```

That's it.  That's all that needs to be in this top-level script file (with the exception of any script bootstrapping) if you embrace the concepts of routing and inversion of control.

The `Router` of course would need to hold the logic mapping request properties to controllers - oftentimes with that mapping be captured in a config file. That might look something like this (here I am using JSON representation, but this could take many forms):

```
{
    "action": {
        "get_notification": "NotificationController",
        "other_action": {
            "module": {
                "some_module": "OtherActionSomeModuleController",
                "other_module" "OtherActionOtherModuleController",
                ...
             },
             "other_module: { ... },
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

This could, for example, just map various actions, modules, etc. to different controller class names. Each of these controllers would need to be able to accept a `Request` object as a dependency and know what to do with it when `execute()` is called. The router would instantiate the appropriate class and then pass the `Request` to it.

As a developer wanting to add new action/behaviors to the system, all you would need to do is build a new controller for it, and then add the new controller to the route map as appropriate. You would not need to change one bit of code in the rest of the application (i.e. the top-level routing script) unless you were introducing a non-compatible change for some reason (i.e. your whole route map would need to change).

And in case you were wondering what happened to all the handling of invalid requests, that would be something that would live with the `Router`.  If it cannot successfully route the request, it could just instantiate an `InvalidRequestController` or similar to fulfill the request.

So your `getController()` method might look like:

```
// assume the config shown above has been loaded into a multi-dimensional array
// in $map property.
public function getController(Request $request) {
      if(!array_key_exists($request->action, $this->map) {
          return new InvalidRequestController($request);
      }
      $action = $this->map[$request->action];
      if(!is_array($action)) {
          return new {$action}($request);
      }
      if(!array_key_exists($request->module, $action)) {
          return new InvalidRequestController($request);
      }

      return new {$action[$request->module]}($request);
}
```

---

A few other considerations:

- You really ought to consider using an autoloader (ideally a [PSR-4](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjf3MKS5uXTAhUnslQKHWtwA54QFggnMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.php-fig.org%2Fpsr%2Fpsr-4%2F&usg=AFQjCNGYMPKfRITHHnWOwoW6z_Y8TmHNPQ&sig2=uPEQMOeOprOmHTDQmh4d0Q) compliant one).  Having a bunch of `include`/`require` statements littered throughout your code to load classes is really a very old way of doing things.
- You **really** should consider sending appropriate HTTP error codes when your application receives mal-formed requests (i.e. all of your "invalid request" conditionals).
- What is the purpose of having both `action` and `module` if you only have a single `action` you are listening for and everything else goes to `modules`?  It seems like this could perhaps be just a single layer of routing as opposed to the nesting routing construct this code implies.
- I don't know what `$module->verify()` does, but is it a potential security concern with passing unvalidated POST data deeper into the application?
- When you have variable interpolation like this `$module->$action()`, consider using braces to eliminate ambiguity - `$module->{$action}()` (as you could theoretically have `$module->{$action()} usage`).
- There are a bunch of bad coding resources/examples out there on the web (especially for PHP) that can lead you to bad programming habits, or that are out of touch with modern development approaches.  I will leave you with what I consider to be the best resource to someone learning to work with PHP - http://www.phptherightway.com/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, before I comment on the answer itself, I want to address the last few considerations you suggested first. 1. Although I have not used / knew about an auto loader, so I will look into it, but I thought including a class only when necessay was more efficient. 2. The errors are all logged to a log file, the messages are only sent to the user 3. there is one action with out module, but all modules have multiple actions/methods 4. the purpose of verify was to check if action/method to be called exits and is not forbidden

Comment: @feetnappy Pretty move every modern PHP application framework and application rely on class autoloading. Yes, there is overhead, but nothing that 99.9% of the application in the world need to worry about.  Not to mention that developer time costs significantly more than server resources these days so maintainability and simplicity of code typically trumps worrying about maybe having to scale you application servers marginally sooner than your otherwise have.  manual class loading should be considered a micro-optimization.

Comment: About the json, (if i am to use it) so all the if else / switch logic will be in that, so when i load the file as object, i just have to match the key and call corresponding method name associated with the key. Is that right?

Comment: And with autoloading you don't have to do anything more than instantiate your class to have it be loaded automatically for you.

Comment: @feetnappy I should also mention that as you build your software, you oftentimes need to rely on third party libraries mad available on Packagist or similar.  Using a autoloading approach as required for composer-compatible packages makes adding such libraries to your application dead simple.  That being said, if you happened to have a particular application which does one specific thing with few classes files and really needs to be optimized for performance, then perhaps autoloading is not the best approach.  But I would bias application development towards autoloading.

Comment: @fettnappy regarding JSON (or other config file - it could be an actually PHP array as well). Yes I am suggesting that the router would just see if the information in the request maps to something in the config file and of not, it is treated as invalid request.

Comment: @MikeBrant the autoloader has to be defined manually right? using `spl_autoload_register` and also I am really interested the JSON method. I will try to implement it now

Comment: @feetnappy Correct with regards to autoloader.  Here is FIG-provided examples of PSR-4 compliant autolaoders https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader-examples.md

Comment: @MikeBrant One last thing, does all the data have to be in a single JSON file? Can JSON files be  included like php to keep it definitions of different modules separate

Comment: @feetnappy If you begin to move your self into the world of using Composer-based projects, you basically don't have to think about the autoloader at all, as Composer provides it.

Comment: @feetnappy It doesn't have to be JSON. It can be whatever you want and what makes sense for your application - loading as many or as few config files as you need to build your application route mapping. What I showed was just an example and doesn't really consider everything you might need for production system.  There are good libraries out their for routing, such that you make not even need to reinvent the wheel there.

Comment: @MikeBrant as i am new to web dev in general, so i learming everything by hard-coding. Once i am know how stuff works, i plan to switch to libraries. Anyway, thanks again. You have been very helpful.

Comment: @feetnappy I assumes you were some what new - that's why I linked the phptherightway site.  It might not all make sense now, but should help be a roadmap to guide your learnings.  There are a lot of bad/dated examples out there. For example the old "autoloading is bad for performance" line of thinking.  That is rooted in development practices of the past.

Comment: @feetnappy By the way. My comment on HTTP error codes is a different thing than error logging.  When a client (for example a browser) sends you a mal-formed request. You should likely be sending a 4XX response code to let the calling application know they did something wrong in sending the request and that perhaps the need to treat the response differently than they would a 200 response.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: @MikeBrant I am using         `error: function(jqXHR, exception) {if (jqXHR.status === 0) {...} else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {...} else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {...} else if (exception === "parsererror") {...} else if (exception === "timeout") {...} else if (exception === "abort") {...} else {...}}`, to handle ajax errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58531/discussion-between-mike-brant-and-feetnappy).